# Unable to talk to a FT232H device on Mac OS X 10.11 ( El Capitan )

Tags: python, macos, ftdi

I wanted to work with an FT232H device using a python library and I ended up using devttys0's mpsse library.

https://github.com/devttys0/libmpsse

I followed the instructions to install it successfully. But I kept getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gpio.py", line 7, in <module>
    io = MPSSE(GPIO)
  File "/Users/tabishimran/code/devttys0-mpsse/src/mpsse.py", line 70, in __init__
    raise Exception, self.ErrorString()
Exception: device not found
```

The instructions said to install libftdi from source. So i downloaded the library and installed it from source. But I'm still seeing the same error.
The system information tool is able to detect the device connected to the usb. It outputs :

```
  Product ID:   0x6014
  Vendor ID:    0x0403  (Future Technology Devices International Limited)
  Version:  9.00
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: FTDI
  Location ID:  0x14100000 / 2
  Current Available (mA):   1000
  Current Required (mA):    500
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

But I'm unable to communicate with the device. Any help would be appreciated!